# mysqli bind param parameters error

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying out using prepared statements for the first time and running into the following issue with the below code

Error :

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_stmt, boolean given

Code :

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "INSERT INTO fragrances VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sssssssssssssssssss', $name, $description, $essentialoils, $topnotes, $middlenotes, $basenotes, $reference, $year, $type, $price, $fragrancehouse, $triangle, $extractname, $extractreference, $extractprice, $extractfragrancehouse, $disccolour, $collarcolour, $actuatorcolour);

         mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

I've looked at many different questions on here and none of their solutions seem to apply for my problem, does anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: You should add the column names from the table `"INSERT INTO fragrances (column, names, here) VALUES (....)"`. The warning in this case means that there is an error in your query

Comment: still having the same error with the fieldnames insitu

Comment: And a field like `type` is that a string or an integer?

Comment: Becasue if a variable contains an integer in the `bind_param` part the `s` should be replaced with an `i`

Comment: @SuperDJ all fields are strings